# limit the number of entries and restart after break in the for loop

Tags: php, yii2

I have a model and ready-made data in a table. In this model, I added a new field and made a connection with another table.

And in order not to manually fill in these fields for each record, I want to create a migration that will automatically fill in this field for all records.

Relationship table has two fields: post_id and author_id.

I am trying to do like this:

```
$posts = Posts::find()->all();

foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
    for($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < $index; $j++, $i++) {
        if ($j >= 4) {
          break;
        }
        $item = new PostAuthor();
        $item->setAttribute('post_id', $posts->id);
        $item->setAttribute('author_id', $j + 1);
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
$posts = Posts::find()->all();

foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $index && $i < 4; $i++) {
        $item = new PostAuthor();
        $item->setAttribute('post_id', $posts->id);
        $item->setAttribute('author_id', $i + 1);
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

But I get the same, only when j reaches 4, the cycle does not start again, and it adds everything else from 1 to 4:

[image]

Is it possible to make the loop start over for the post IDs I'm circling in the screenshot?

In idea my table should look like this

[image]

Comment: "But I would like to redo all this" - what keeps you from doing this? PHP itself does not know about any "offset function", but it should not be too hard to write one

Comment: not a function but a method, I was wrong

Comment: You didn't post enough information to make this solvable. You should post some data about the ideal final result. Also, in your screenshot, you are showing values but no column names.

Comment: You want to assign each of four authors to each post? If that is correct then there is a lot simple solution.

Comment: From the image provided, its unclear which is the id ? When j reaches 4 you want to restart the loop with offeset 4 ?

Comment: @benkov When j reaches 4, I need the cycle to start over, and for the next posts, the counter starts again. That is, for ID 71 there should be only one value and not 4, for ID 93 2 values, etc.

Comment: @katsarov When j reaches 4, I need the cycle to start over, and for the next posts, the counter starts again. That is, for ID 71 there should be only one value and not 4, for ID 93 2 values, etc.

Comment: Added a screenshot to the post of how my table should look like in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$posts = Posts::find()->all();
$authors = [1,2,3,4]; //ids of the authors
$i = 1;
foreach($posts as $post){
  $postAuthors = array_slice($authors, 0, $i);
  $post->authors()->sync($postAuthors); //I assume your relation is belongsToMany(), otherwise you can foreach $postAuthors to create PostAuthor
  $i++;
  //you can use $i+=rand(1,4) instead to add more randomness
  if($i>4){
    $i=0; //settings to 0 will produce each 5 post to not have authors. If you set to 1 all posts will have author
  }
}
```

For each post we take N authors, sync relation then reset counter

Comment: nothing has changed, I end up with the same table, what's in the first screenshot

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve? Because of the code I see that you want for each post you want to add each of authors

Comment: That's right, add an author_id to each post, but add it so that each post has a different author_id, someone has 1 and 2, someone just has 1, someone doesn't have it at all, as in the last screenshot